# Facebook asking for list of friends without user_friends permission added on login with system account iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-permissions

When I use native login, Facebook only asks for the permissions I add (email), but when I switch to the System Account login I get this text: "'App name' would like to access your basic profile and list of friends". I have breakpointed the FBSDKLoginManager and I see that it adds "email" permission if my app wants to reauthorize the user, commenting out that "email" is used as a proxy for basic_info permission. And I use reauthorization. So, is the list of friends part of the basic_info permissions still when using system account? Can this be some leftover bug in the latest FB SDK, or am missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The system dialog is managed by Apple and not by the FB SDK itself so there is little that can be done on the Facebook side of things unless Apple updates their implementation of this. basic_info used to include the friend list but has been replaced by public_profile which does not include this (it is a separate permission, user_friends). The easiest way to find out what set of permissions are granted by this dialog is to log the access token to the console and then use the FB Debugger to see the list of permissions https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have got: user_friends, email, public_profile, which I could also see from code, but I never add user_friends permission. I can even see that both user_friends and public_profile permissions are removed on system login in the FBSDKLoginManager, but it seems that that does not work.